# How to restore purchase within in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In-app purchase functionality in my iPhone app. In that I have given Restore Option. Sometimes, when I tapped restore button, I am not getting any product ids from App Store. But I have done purchases using Apple ids (Test User Account).

But sometime it works with some-other Apple Ids (Test User account). Why is this behaving differently?

How long should I wait to restore the purchase once after purchase is done. I use to check it on after 10min. Is that OK?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I really wouldn't worry about it.  No one is ever going to make an in-app purchase and then delete and re-download the app in the span of 10 minutes.  If you have gotten it to work, you should be fine for any realistic case.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Perhaps this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apple (and Google) does give the option to 'save' the purchase history for you so a user can restore it if he deleted his app or switched to a new device. The functionality given by Google and Apple is very limited, however and you can easily implement a better functionality on your own.

- Set up a server side for user verification
- Make your own restore purchase function
- Apply some rules on top of it (fraud protection, expiration, logs, ...).

To do that, you need to configure all products as "consumable" or in Google "unmanaged" and basically manage everything on your side.